# How to use Select by Attributes query with semicolons?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I am trying to select multiple (50 or more) unique numeric records using ArcGIS 10's **"Select by Attributes"** using semicolons ';' after each record which it verifies as good to go.
Please see **[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1PBm.jpg)** of where it verifies my expression "successful".

Yet when OK is hit it **only selects the first record.**

Do we really have to enter ***"xyz" = 1 OR "xyz" = 2 OR "xyz" = 3*** etc. etc. to have multiple records selected?

Comment: Yes. That's a SQL thing, not an ArcGIS thing (since all ArcGIS is doing is sending the text as a _where_ condition to the database server).

Comment: yes better than ESRI Forums because we answer non-esri questions too - GIS is more than one company/community

Comment: Love this gis.stackexchange, there is so much easy-to-find Helpful information here! Very true about it being a SQL question and how GIS is so much more than Esri... if only Esri could understand that, Ha!

Comment: Is there any better way to do this?? Because I need to search like 400 values!

Comment: Please create a new question with the details of what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and any issues you're running into. You can link back to this question for reference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the IN operator instead:

```
"xyz" in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Glad to help! This might also be worth bookmarking:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/

Comment: Ah soo... most helpful. Thanks again.  http://i.imgur.com/M2ThI.jpg